# ConditionalWeakTable example doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm playing around with `ConditionalWeakTable` for the first time, so I figured I'd run the [example from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=net-7.0#examples).

This doesn't compile out of the box... I had to change this:

```
else if (cwt.TryGetValue(wr2.Target, out data))
```

...to this:

```
else if (cwt.TryGetValue((ManagedClass)wr2.Target, out data))
```

Even then though, my console spits out `Data created at 07/03/2023 12:56:02`... which is not what the docs say it should be doing:

```
// The example displays the following output:
//       No strong reference to mc2 exists.
```

This is my project file (the only other file in the solution, a part from the example code):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I did try targeting netcore 3.1 to see if that would make a difference but still no joy.

Am I missing something really basic here?

Comment: It's very poor example code as you note. It works if you do the creation of `mc2` in a separate function, due to the way GC tracks object lifetime in Debug mode. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/unZjUn There should be a duplicate of this somewhere: GC does not collect in Debug mode if the object is alive in the same function